# ImgButton click in mvvvm xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, command

I have a code written in xaml.cs file, But i want to do it in viewmodel file, but i don't know how can i do it, i tried to do command but this is didn't worked and i'm just a beginner so don't have many ideas about this pattern and commadns

this is my code :

```
private async void ItemImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var appoitment = (Appoitment)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;
            AppintmentService appintmentService = new AppintmentService();
            await appintmentService.DeleteFollowup(appoitment.PatientID, appoitment.ID);
            await DisplayAlert("Delted", "The patient Deleteed", "Ok");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PatientProfileFollowUpPage());
        }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: why don't you show us what you tried - and explain the specific problem you had with it - so we can help you fix it?

Comment: What doc or tutorial have you read? Google `xamarin forms mvvm command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could binding Command for the ImageButton. A simple code below for your reference.

Xaml:

```
 <ImageButton Command="{Binding ImgButtonCommand}"></ImageButton>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Page1ViewModel
{
    public Command ImgButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        ImgButtonCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            //something you want to do 
        });
    }
}
```

Binding for the page:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext=new Page1ViewModel();
    }

   
}
```

Comment: What if you want to get `object sender` and `EventArgs e` from that ImageButton into a command? I have a custom property on my `ImageButton` and I really need that `object sender` but I cannot get it. You got an idea?